how to plot boxplot with title using for loop with subplot
I am having data frame like this with thousands of records and 12 columns.



AMT_ANNUITY
AMT_GOODS_PRICE




2510
25840


251.58
479.35



I want to plot boxplot columns with title and subplot using pandas. How to plot it?
With this code I am getting boxplots with title but without subplot
df4=['AMT_ANNUITY', 'AMT_GOODS_PRICE', 'EXT_SOURCE_2', 'EXT_SOURCE_3',
       'YEARS_BEGINEXPLUATATION_AVG', 'FLOORSMAX_AVG',
       'YEARS_BEGINEXPLUATATION_MODE', 'FLOORSMAX_MODE',
       'YEARS_BEGINEXPLUATATION_MEDI', 'FLOORSMAX_MEDI', 'TOTALAREA_MODE',
       'DAYS_LAST_PHONE_CHANGE']
# df3 is actual dataframe
for item in df4:     
    sns.boxplot(x=df3[item])
    plt.show()

with this code I am getting boxplot with subplot but without title
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=4, constrained_layout=True)                 
fig.subplots_adjust(left= 0, bottom=0, right=3, top=12, wspace=0.09, hspace=0.3)
for ax, column in zip(axes.flatten(), df4):       
    sns.boxplot(df3[column],ax=ax)

I want boxplot with both subplot and title. How to write code for this?

Remove the call to fig.subplots_adjust(...) as it cuts off titles (and does wrong things with the right and top whitespace).  Change sns.boxplot(df3[column],ax=ax) to sns.boxplot(data=df3, y=column, ax=ax) and maybe add ax.set_title(column) and ax.set_ylabel(''). You can call plt.tight_layout() at the end to nicely fit titles and tick labels.
